# IPleaseWaitService not working after upgrade to 5.0

Tags: catel

I have an app that I use the `IPleaseWaitService` working fine when using Catel v 4.5.4, but when I updated to v 5.0.0, the `IPleaseWaitService` does not display the `UpdateStatus` and only displays a little spinner that doesn't go away on `Hide` (the only way to 'hide' the spinner is to use `Pop`). Additionally the views are not greyed out and not active like the previous version used to do.

Is there anything special that I have to do to implement the `IPleaseWaitService` with Catel 5.0.0? (nothing indicated in the documentation)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PleaseWaitHelper` (used for the WPF implementation) has been removed to simplify the code-base for Catel 5. See https://github.com/Catel/Catel/issues/1010 for more information>

The good news is that it's all open source so you can copy / paste the implementation of the `PleaseWaitService` from Catel 4.5 and use that one if you prefer it.

Another implementation you could look at can be found in [Orchestra](https://github.com/WildGums/Orchestra/blob/65efe31043748f61fb9071972f5b4cf64037b7e3/src/Orchestra.Shell/Orchestra.Shell.Shared/Services/ProgressPleaseWaitService.cs), where it embeds itself in the shell (at the bottom).